# SQL: SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM $TABLENAME "Rows" value is 0 even if it has a row

Tags: mysql

When I try to `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM $TABLENAME` some of the tables have the `'Rows' = 0` even when it has a row (mostly when it has only 1 row)

Comment: InnoDB doesn't keep the row count up to date. You need to use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename`

Comment: That explains everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB doesn't keep the row count up to date. as this great man mentioned in the comment.